# What "no code generation“ in Spring Boot means

Tags: java, spring-boot, code-generation

Spring Boot doc states "Absolutely no code generation and no requirement for XML configuration."

What is "code generation" in that context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It states that [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) doesn't generate or edit code

> Spring Boot does not generate code or make edits to your files. Instead, when you start your application, Spring Boot dynamically wires up beans and settings and applies them to your application context.

It means no extra code is generated and executed except your code and spring boot dependencies you added

Comment: I know. Can you give an example that there is extra code in other framework or application? Thank you.

Comment: @awxiaoxian2020 JavaPoet https://github.com/square/javapoet `Source file generation can be useful when doing things such as annotation processing or interacting with metadata files`